# C# Fill Listbox with mysqllist

Tags: c#, mysql, listbox

thats my code
I try to get a specific row from my mysql table to my listbox
Somebody can tell me the error why all work fine but no Item was showed in Listbox?
The Code to clear the Listbox dont work also...
Any Ideas?

```
        string MyConString = "SERVER=" + ip + ";" + "DATABASE=" + db + ";" + "UID=" + user + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + pw + ";";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
        string column = (string)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
        string query = "SELECT * from t_string;";

        List<string>[] list = new List<string>[1];
        list[0] = new List<string>();

        connection.Open();
        //Create Command
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        //Create a data reader and Execute the command
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //Read the data and store them in the list
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            list[0].Add(dataReader[column] + "");
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Starting");
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        //Clear Listbox
        form1.listBox1.Items.Clear();
        // Add List to Textbox
        form1.listBox1.Items.AddRange(list);
        form1.listBox1.Refresh();
        MessageBox.Show("Finished");

        //close Data Reader
        dataReader.Close();
```

Comment: You get any exception or error message? Did you debug your code step by step?

Comment: There is no Error or Exception the Application still running well.

Comment: @Sajeetharan winforms sorry for dont post it

Comment: `form1.listBox1.Items.AddRange(list);` Wouldn't that be `form1.listBox1.Items.AddRange(list[0]);` ? Do you know how many data you have actually read?

Comment: `there are in more than 5000 Rows` Do you mean in the DataBase or in your list[0]?

Comment: @TaW atm there are in more than 5000 Rows form1.listBox1.Items.AddRange(list); That code dont give an error form1.listBox1.Items.AddRange(list[0]); This one give an error       So i think the first one should be correct. Another way was           form1.listBox1.Items.Add(list[0]); This way dont give an error too but nothing happen too like the first one...  My function on top wasnt in Form1, may this was the problem that the ListBox dont get the Values?

Comment: @TaW The list should be cleared before with this: form1.listBox1.Items.Clear(); So i collect every row of my column in Database and add it to my listbox

Comment: Was AFK. So you say, that there are 5000 records in the listbox (which is a __LOT__) but you don't see them? Not even if you wait a while? Are there VScrollbars? Can you turn them on to see if they are usable and only the display value of the column is at fault?

Comment: @TaW For checking that i put in MessageBox.Show("Starting"); and MessageBox.Show("Finished"); before the ListBox1.Clear(); and behind the form1.listBox1.Items.AddRange(list); and it dont take more than  1/2 seconds to say Starting and Finished. Look on top on the code.

Comment: Make that :        ` MessageBox.Show("Finished with " + form1.listBox1.Items.Count.ToString() + " items in the list.");`

Answer (score 0):

Because i dont post here a Question for getting the answer of any other people without work parallel by my own i worked out a Answer by myself :P

I user a DataTable and with a Class for Fill the ComboBox With my ID's

```
            string MyConString = "SERVER=" + Config_Settings.ip + ";" + "DATABASE=" + Config_Settings.db + ";" + "UID=" + Config_Settings.user + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + Config_Settings.pw + ";";
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
            string command = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM t_string";
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command, connection);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            List<MyModel> models = new List<MyModel>();
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                MyModel model = new MyModel
                {
                    Name = (string)row[0]
                };
                models.Add(model);
            }

            bindingSource1.DataSource = models;
            comboBox1.DataSource = bindingSource1.DataSource;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Languae";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "Languae";
```

AND

```
    public class MyModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```